# How did shutting down a heavy use bridge in the Bridge-gate scandal benefit Christie?

Tags: united-states

So, due to other high profile scandals, I haven't been following bridge-gate very closely. That being said, I understand that its Chris Christie's NJ administration had something to do with shutting down a heavy use bridge to spite and or get revenge against a Democrat for something or other.

I fail to see how inconveniencing the plebs could do anything to harm a politician. Could someone explain this scandal in a bit more detail than the various slanted news articles around it?  Specifically how the Christie administration benefited from the slowdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Lee_lane_closure_scandal#Possible_motives) covers the whole scandal pretty well.

In brief, the Democratic mayor of Fort Lee didn't endorse Christie during his 2013 reelection campaign (as many other Democratic politicians did), so Christie's staffers closed lanes on the bridge in such a way that traffic in Fort Lee essentially gridlocked all day.  People were then told that it was the mayor's fault.